# Remove brackets in Sweave output

Tags: r, sweave

I want to know if there is a way to print R object directly in a text (Sweave), but directly in a line of text.

I'd like to print this code

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

YO MANNNNNNN 2+2 = 
<<here, results=tex, echo=FALSE>>=
2+2
@
YEAHHHH!

\end{document}
```

And I want an output similar to this:

```
YO MANNNNNNN 2+2 = 4 YEAHHHH!
```

But, R is adding the answer brackets like this

```
YO MANNNNNNN 2+2 = [1] 4YEAHHHH!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
% \SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

YO MANNNNNNN 2+2 = \Sexpr{2+2} YEAHHHH! 

\end{document}
```

n.b. For me commenting out `\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}` worked just fine, but you made need to uncomment depending on your setup.

**Prints:**

```
YO MANNNNNNN 2+2 = 4 YEAHHHH!
```

---

**Update** - extra info per comment...

You can define an object within a 'chunk' to be later evaluated in line using `\Sexpr{}`

```
<<somechunk, results='tex',echo=FALSE, results='hide'>>=
x <- 2
@

Inline evaluation of x prints the number \Sexpr{x}.
```

Comment: Nice Thanks a lot. Its working perfectly for me. Also it is possible to put an object like this 
`objecthere=2+2
YO MANNNNNNN 2+2 = \Sexpr{objecthere} YEAHHHH!`